# Update view to a dataset in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a datasource on a WPF form in shape of a detailed view of my table. When I search for a specific row, I want it to update in the binded textboxes, but they only show blank.

```
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource employeesViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("employeesViewSource")));
        Yello.YelloDataSet yelloDataSet = ((Yello.YelloDataSet)(this.FindResource("yelloDataSet")));
        var adapter = new YelloDataSetTableAdapters.EmployeesTableAdapter();

        var row = yelloDataSet.Employees.Select("ID='11'");
        employeesViewSource.View.MoveCurrentTo(row);
```

If i for example do:

```
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource employeesViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("employeesViewSource")));
        employeesViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToNext();
```

It works perfectly and updates with the bindings. Am i using the wrong function or am i missing something??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what is happening is that you are selecting a row from `yelloDataSet` and after that you try to move to that row in `employeesViewSource`, but the problem is that the rows are not the same,although the data maybe is. To move to a row in your `CollectionViewSource`,you must search it inside the collection. So you'll do something like this:

```
var row = employeesViewSource.View.OfType<DataSet>().Select("ID='11'");
employeesViewSource.View.MoveCurrentTo(row);
```

**Edit**

Ok, i answered without actually trying the code and i was wrong. Try the next code, i think it should work for you:

```
var row = employeesViewSource.View.OfType<DataRowView>()
          .Where(x => x.Row.Field<string>("ID") == "11")
          .FirstOrDefault();
employeesViewSource.View.MoveCurrentTo(row);
```

But it depends on what type is the CollectionViewSource. I've tried it with a DataTable. It may change if it is a DataSet, for example. If this does not work, tell me what type the source is...

Comment: Thank you for the answer but employeesViewSource does not have a select method, not what i can find.

Comment: Ok, i made a mistake. You've got to cast your `CollectionViewSource` before using `Select`. See my updated code @MagnusWirström

Comment: This gives me this error: CS0411 The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Select<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @MagnusWirström see my edited answer. I hope it works for you.

Comment: With a small modification this worked. This is the answer: var row = employeesViewSource.View.OfType<DataRowView>()
          .Where(x => x.Row.Field<Int32>("ID") == 11)
          .FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Ok,that's just because your ID field was an int, i didn't know what type it was. But glad it worked. @MagnusWirström

Comment: Yes, sorry I was not clear on that, but thank you very much to help me solving this.